# Setting onclick property for input

Tags: javascript

I need to set `onclick` property to the newly created element (`input` tag). It should be function with arguments. I use this: `addButton.onclick = addToBasket(aHref[i].innerHTML, aHref[i].href);`

But the problem is that this function calls automatically when window is loaded, but I need simply to set property. By the way if I use function without arguments like this: `addButton.onclick = addToBasket;` it works (isn't called automatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead:

```
addButton.onclick = function(){
    addToBasket(aHref[i].innerHTML, aHref[i].href);
}
```

`onclick` expects a *function-definition*. Another possibility is:

```
addButton.onclick = addToBasket;
```

But in this last one you will need to get the args from the function's inside, or with global variables.

It is because when you use `()` you are invoking the *function-definition* which will return some value or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
addButton.onclick = function(){ addToBasket(aHref[i].innerHTML, aHref[i].href)};
```

The difference is that the `addToBasket` call here is done on click, not before.